# Google Cloud Storage(Python): How to check when was file last modified?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We have a job that checks if a file on the cloud storage has been modified. If so, then it reads the data from the file and processes it further.

I want to know if there is an API to check when a file on the cloud storage was last modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App engine [Cloud Storage client library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#stat) will expose this information to you. This library also has dev appserver support. Getting started has an [example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted).

Comment: Yes, it seems they are deprecating the Cloud Storage API in favor of the new client library.

Answer (score 6):

You can now do this using the [official Python lib for Google Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-python).

```
from google.cloud import storage


def blob_metadata(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Prints out a blob's metadata."""
    # bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
    # blob_name = 'your-object-name'

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)

    print("Blob: {}".format(blob.name))
    print("Bucket: {}".format(blob.bucket.name))
    print("Storage class: {}".format(blob.storage_class))
    print("ID: {}".format(blob.id))
    print("Size: {} bytes".format(blob.size))
    print("Updated: {}".format(blob.updated))
    print("Generation: {}".format(blob.generation))
    print("Metageneration: {}".format(blob.metageneration))
    print("Etag: {}".format(blob.etag))
    print("Owner: {}".format(blob.owner))
    print("Component count: {}".format(blob.component_count))
    print("Crc32c: {}".format(blob.crc32c))
    print("md5_hash: {}".format(blob.md5_hash))
    print("Cache-control: {}".format(blob.cache_control))
    print("Content-type: {}".format(blob.content_type))
    print("Content-disposition: {}".format(blob.content_disposition))
    print("Content-encoding: {}".format(blob.content_encoding))
    print("Content-language: {}".format(blob.content_language))
    print("Metadata: {}".format(blob.metadata))
    print("Temporary hold: ", "enabled" if blob.temporary_hold else "disabled")
    print(
        "Event based hold: ",
        "enabled" if blob.event_based_hold else "disabled",
    )
    if blob.retention_expiration_time:
        print(
            "retentionExpirationTime: {}".format(
                blob.retention_expiration_time
            )
        )
```

In your case you will have to look at `blob.updated` property

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto):

```
>>> import boto
>>> conn = boto.connect_gs()
>>> bucket = conn.get_bucket('yourbucket')
>>> k = bucket.get_key('yourkey')
>>> k.last_modified
'Tue, 04 Dec 2012 17:44:57 GMT'
```

There is also an [App Engine Python interface](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/functions) to cloud storage, but I don't think it exposes the metadata you want.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage has an API, which you can use to get the creation time of an object

see https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects

Comment: Aren't there any Python APIs for this? Our code is in Python.

Comment: The Google API Client Library for Python supports the beta Cloud Storage API: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/storage/v1beta1/python/latest/ Though you will need to enable this on your API dashboard by requesting access first.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the solution mentioned by @orby above using `blob.updated` to get the latest file. But there are more than 450+ files in the bucket and this script takes around 6-7 minutes to go through all the files and provide the latest latest file. I suppose the `blob.updated` part takes some time to process. Is there any faster way to do this?

```
    files = bucket.list_blobs()    
    fileList = [file.name for file in files if '.dat' in file.name]
     
    latestFile = fileList[0]
    latestTimeStamp = bucket.get_blob(fileList[0]).updated
            
    for i in range(len(fileList)):
        
        timeStamp = bucket.get_blob(fileList[i]).updated
        
        if timeStamp > latestTimeStamp:
            latestFile = fileList[i]
            latestTimeStamp = timeStamp
    
    print(latestFile)
```

Comment: You don't have to call `bucket.get_blob(fileList[i]).updated` since you already have the blob in fileList if you put the whole blob in the list and not only the filename. Then you can call `i.updated`

Comment: This will use seconds:     ```files = bucket.list_blobs()
    fileList = [file for file in files if '.dat' in file.name]

    latestFile = None

    for i in fileList:

        if not latestFile:
            latestFile = i
            continue

        if i.updated > latestFile.updated:
            latestFile = i

    print(latestFile)```